# rails: how to post multi images with one post - facebook koala gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, koala

I want to post multiple images with one post.

But I don't know how does it.

> ```
> data = {
>   caption: @post.legacy_capatable_text,
>   url: @post.legacy_capatable_image_url,
>   suburl1: @post.legacy_capatable_subimage1_url,
>   suburl2: @post.legacy_capatable_subimage2_url,
>   suburl3: @post.legacy_capatable_subimage3_url,
>   privacy: {
>     value: 'SELF'
>   }
> }
>
> data[:link] = @post.post_url if @post.post_url
>
> @graph.put_connections("me", "photos", data)
> ```

But there is no working.

Only one image is posting.
suburl 1,2,3 is not working.